# java simple date pattern TO oracle sql date pattern

Tags: java, sql, oracle, date

I have following web application: 
Users can enter java simple date format patterns and a date (of course matching to the java simple date format pattern) and I want to store these date in an oracle database.

Therefore I need to translate the java simple date format pattern into the oracle pattern.
E.g:

- "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss" **into** "DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS"
- "dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss" **into** "DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS"
- "dd-MM-yy HH:mm" **into** "DD-MM-YY HH24:MI"

and so on.

Instead of the following code just having one SimpleDateFormat I would like to have all or at least a big bunch of SimpleDateFormatPatterns translated into Oracle pattern:

```
SimpleDateFormat sFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
String sqlSnippet = "TO_DATE('" + sFormat.format(date) + "','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')";
```

Is there a library or maybe just a mapping list to do this?

Thanks.

Edit:
I need to build the SQL by hand as the user defines the criteria, compare operators and joins in the user interface.
In the end I have something like this

```
AND col2 > TO_DATE('26-09-2012','DD-MM-YYYY')
```

Answer (score 3):

> Therefore I need to translate the java simple date format pattern into the oracle pattern

No, you don't. You should instead use a `PreparedStatement`, and call [`setDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setDate-int-java.sql.Date-) or [`setTimestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTimestamp-int-java.sql.Timestamp-) on it to specify the value you're interested in.

Avoid string conversions unless they're *fundamentally* part of what you're trying to do (e.g. displaying a date/time in a UI). For simply transferring information from your app to your database or vice versa, you should reduce the number of conversions required as far as possible.

Comment: Thanks for that fast reply but I need to build up this sql statement by hand.    The User can define criteria for the WHERE clause in the user interface (joins and further stuff as well) as well as the compare operators. Maybe I can use the inner API of the setDate.

Comment: Just because you need to build *some* of the SQL dynamically doesn't mean you have to do it *all* dynamically. I *strongly, strongly, strongly* urge you not to do so. Specifying values directly in SQL is *fraught* with danger. You can still create the SQL dynamically, but include parameter specifiers in there and use `PreparedStatement.setDate` etc.

Comment: Ok, I will try to solve it this way. Anyway currently I can not imagine if I just give a `Date` how the method will know if I want to end up with SQL like this `DD-MM-YYYY` or this `DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS` which makes a big difference in the WHERE clause.

Comment: @user239293: Why would it make a big difference in the where clause? What do you expect the difference to be after you've called `TO_DATE`? You really need to think about what fundamental data you're using. Maybe you need to differentiate between `DATE` and `TIMESTAMP` values instead, and make sure your fields are of the appropriate type.

Comment: You are right. It doesn't make a difference in WHERE clause. I mixed it up with trunc and to_char.

Answer (score 0):

The [Answer by Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25303478/642706) is correct but is now outdated in referring to some legacy classes. The `java.sql.Date` and `java.sql.Timestamp` and related classes are now supplanted by the *java.time* classes, `LocalDate` and `Instant` respectively. But your Question demands the [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) class.

## Smart objects, not dumb strings

You objects to represent your date-time values. As of JDBC 4.2 and later, you can directly exchange *java.time* objects with your database.

Your inputs lack any indicator of time zone or offset-from-UTC. So parse in Java as a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) for storage in a column of a type similar to SQL-standard `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`.

```
DateTimeFormatter f1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MM-uuuu HH:mm:ss" ) ;
DateTimeFormatter f2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MM-uu HH:mm:ss" ) ;
DateTimeFormatter f3 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MM-uu HH:mm" ) ;
```

Choose a formatter by length of the input string.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( myInputString , f2 ) ;
```

> I need to build the SQL by hand as the user defines the criteria, compare operators and joins in the user interface. In the end I have something like this
>
> String sqlSnippet = "TO_DATE('" + sFormat.format(date) + "','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')";

**No, do not embed your date-time value as text in a String of SQL.** Instead, use a `PreparedStatement` with `?` placeholders replaced with your `LocalDateTime` object.

```
String sql = "SELECT when FROM tbl WHERE when > ? ;" ;
```

Pass the object to be slipped into that placeholder at runtime.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ldt ) ;
```

Retrieval:

```
LocalDateTime ldt = myResultSet.getObject( … ; LocalDateTime.class ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).